# Numerical - Optimization : Gauss-seidel implementation?

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

Reading through a book of numerical optimization the very first algorithm explained is the Gauss-Seidel one.

Suppose we want to solve the problem

$$
\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} f(x)
$$

Assume $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, assume it is also differentiabile, assume the method converge.

Let $g(x) = \nabla f(x)$, so this is a vector. The algorithm is explained as follows

1. All coordinates are fixed, say to 0.
2. The first coordinate is modified by solving the first equation with respect to this first coordinate.
3. And so until $n$
4. The process is repeated.

I'm trying to work out a more detailed procedure, based on that description, because I'm not sure I understand how it is supposed to be eventually implemented, though is a method of little interest.

This is what I've worked out

1. $x^{(0)} = 0$
2. $k \leftarrow 1$
3. $\text{Repeat until convergence}:$
4. $\;\;\; \text{For $j = 1 \ldots n$ do :}$
5. $\;\;\;\;\;\; x^{(k)}_j \leftarrow \text{solve $g_j(x^{(k)}_1,\ldots,x_{j-1}^{(k)},x_{j}^{(k-1)},x_{j+1}^{(k-1)},\ldots,x_n^{(k-1)})$ respect to $x_j^{(k-1)}$}$
6. $\;\;\;\ k \leftarrow k + 1$

Where $\text{convergence}$ is a test for the convergence. So in this algorithm I can apply to solve each $g_j$ any single variable algorithm to solve non linear equations, and I need also to choose the test (could the classic $||x^{(k)} - x^{(k-1)}||_2$ for example.

Comment: Can you clarify what is unclear? is it the solve step in your algorithm?

Comment: That's one thing, yes. The other one is if we need to define a proper metric for the convergence, or it is somehow clear in the algorithm exposition but I can't see it.

Comment: For metrics of the form $\|u\|_p=\left(\sum u_i^p\right^\frac{1}{p}$ the choice is not important because convergence in one metric also implies convergence in all others.

Comment: Shouldn't such norms be equivalent to state what you said?

Comment: For you solution step, it basically means that you fix all $x_i$ with $i\neq k$ and look for a $x_k$ such that $g_k$ vanishes. Geometrically this means you start somewhere on your manifold $f$ and then you follow the gradient in $x_1$ direction until it vanishes. Then you follow the gradient of $x_2$ and so on. When you went through all dimensions you start again with the first dimension.

Comment: Yes but isn't that the case? $\|u\|_n\leq \left(n(\max_iu_i)^n\right)^\frac{1}{n}=n^\frac{1}{n}\max_iu_i=c_n\|u\|_\infty$

Comment: I don't see why that should be the case, generally speaking.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54057/discussion-between-bobo-and-user8469759).

Comment: Did anyone try to solve this problem in MATLAB? I really need a help, please

Comment: Do you need an implementation?